# filebeat cannot assign requested address

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to read the syslog information by filebeat. I have my filebeat installed in docker. I get error message

```
ERROR   [syslog]        syslog/input.go:150     Error starting the servererrorlisten tcp 192.168.1.142:514: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

Here is the config file `filebeat.yml`:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: syslog
  format: rfc5424
  protocol.tcp:
    host: "192.168.1.142:514"


#========================== Elasticsearch output ===============================
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:9200"]
  username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
  password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}

#============================== Dashboards =====================================
setup.dashboards:
  enabled: true

#============================== Kibana =========================================
setup.kibana:
  host: "${KIBANA_HOST}:5601"
  username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
  password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}

#================================== General ===================================
name: test_pc_ecs_log
tags: ["syslog"]
```

Here is `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
# provides UDP syslog reception                                                                                                                                                                        
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")
 
# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
```

I have checked the connection by and telnet are success:

```
netstat -4altunp | grep 514
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:514 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1332/rsyslogd
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:514 0.0.0.0:* 1332/rsyslogd
```

I am following the config example from [input doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-syslog.html).
I would like to ask if anyone set up filebeat for syslog reading.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the container in "host network mode"? Otherwise you won't be able to bind `192.168.1.142`. Also, if you want the port the be available on the host, you need to "publish" it. Check out [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: Thanks, I think I am running in bridge mode. Will try your suggestion.